# jQuery populate select issues with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I've manage to create a sample in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9vkk5/ to illustrate my problem

As you might see it's only an example because I fill the `select` with information by database, this way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load.php?type=clients",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $("#clients").empty();
        var options = '';
        for(var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++){
            options += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].name + "</option>";
        }
        $("#clients").append(options);
        $("#clients").trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
});
```

But the problem I have is totally the same as the jsfiddle example. I would like to, whenever I click the `select` to fill with data from database **but** keep the actual option selected.

**Edit: Solved**.

```
$("#clients").append(options);
$("#clients").val(selected_option); // trick is here
$("#clients").trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: @FrançoisWahl http://jsfiddle.net/9vkk5/3/ it does not. Further than adding `selected_option`, it must edited the `option value`..because all are `1`.

Comment: I see :) Adding unique values are an integral part and most likely an important note to add to your answer :) don't edit your question, just post an answer to your own question adding **all** the changes you had to make linking the working fiddle. In 48 hours you can accept your own answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("#clients").trigger('chosen:refresh');
```

Comment: Solution doesn't work. `stackoverflow !!` never appears.

Comment: Where did you put the $.ajax post?. Can you post more code to have more context on your problem?

Comment: See my answer to `Françoieswahl`.